Compare two timestamp attributes considering only the part DD-MM-YY
I created the following table with sql developer:
CREATE TABLE TEST (  A TIMESTAMP(6) , B TIMESTAMP(6)  );

and entered the following values:
INSERT INTO TEST (A,B) values ('01-APR-2021 12:24:01,861000000', '01-APR-2021 12:24:09,861000000');
INSERT INTO TEST (A,B) values ('01-APR-2021 12:03:53,000000000', '01-APR-2021 12:24:04,000000000');
INSERT INTO TEST (A,B) values ('06-APR-2021 10:37:35,000000000', '07-APR-2021 9:38:36,000000000');
INSERT INTO TEST (A,B) values ('07-APR-2021 12:11:11,000000000', '07-APR-2021 12:11:11,000000000');
INSERT INTO TEST (A,B) values ('08-APR-2021 15:08:54,000000000', '08-APR-2021 15:08:54,000000000');

I want to create a select that returns only the third record:
('06-APR-2021 10:37:35,000000000', '07-APR-2021 9:38:36,000000000')
That is, the record where fields A and B differ by DD-MM-YY.I want to create a select that compares the two fields only on the DD-MM-YY part without considering HH-MM-SS.
I tried with CAST function but it doesn't work:
select * FROM TEST WHERE CAST(A AS DATE)!= CAST(B AS DATE);

             A                               B
01-APR-21 12:24:01,861000000    01-APR-21 12:24:09,861000000
01-APR-21 12:03:53,000000000    01-APR-21 12:24:04,000000000
06-APR-21 10:37:35,000000000    07-APR-21 09:38:36,000000000


You can use TRUNC as it sets the time of the date or timestamp to midnight:
SELECT 
  a,b 
FROM test
WHERE 
  TRUNC(a) <> TRUNC(b);

Read the documentation about that function.
Sample data:



A
B




01-APR-21 12.24.01.000000
01-APR-21 12.24.09.000000


02-APR-21 12.24.01.000000
01-APR-21 12.24.09.000000



Result:



A
B




02-APR-21 12.24.01.000000
01-APR-21 12.24.09.000000



Demo here
Note that using functions in a WHERE clause sometimes slow down the query. If you observe a bad performance, create an index according to the function you use.

Sample data:
SQL> select * from test;

A                         B
------------------------- -------------------------
01.04.21 12:24:01,861000  01.04.21 12:24:09,861000
01.04.21 12:03:53,000000  01.04.21 12:24:04,000000
06.04.21 10:37:35,000000  07.04.21 09:38:36,000000
07.04.21 12:11:11,000000  07.04.21 12:11:11,000000
08.04.21 15:08:54,000000  08.04.21 15:08:54,000000

One option is to apply TO_CHAR function with desired format mask (e.g. DD.MM.YYYY):
SQL> select * from test
  2  where to_char(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy') <> to_char(b, 'dd.mm.yyyy');

A                         B
------------------------- -------------------------
06.04.21 10:37:35,000000  07.04.21 09:38:36,000000

SQL>

